# How to fix image is not showing on PDF using PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, phpspreadsheet

I used PHPSpreadsheet(https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) for generating Excel and PDF.
I added image on first cell and it is showing well on excel but not for PDF.
How to fix this issue?

```
$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooterDrawing();
    $drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
    $drawing->setPath('../upload/14.png');
    $drawing->setHeight(50);
    $drawing->setCoordinates('A1');
    $drawing->setOffsetX(30);
    $drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
```

Comment: Try specifying a full path to the image rather than a relative one.

Comment: I created an answer in case anyone comes across the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a relative path to your image use the full path instead.

Change

```
'../upload/14.png'
```

to something like (modifying for your specific setup)

```
'/home/html/upload/14.png'
```